# How to catch this 403 (Forbidden) error, and render UI again?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, angular, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda to get resized image.

Most time, when I try to use the resized image, the resizing process is done. However, sometimes AWS Lambda hasn't finished its resizing process, which means the image is not ready to use.

So when I use

```
<img [src]="imgUrl">
```

it will show:

[image]

And my console will show:

> GET https://foo.com/bar.jpg 403 (Forbidden)

Is there a way to catch this error, and then render that part of UI / load image again? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can show some other image when src link broken,

```
<img  class="thumbnail-image" [src]="imgUrl" 
onError="this.src='./Imagefolder/placeholder.jpg';"  alt="..." />
```

**Update**:

Somehow I found (according to your comment)that `onError` is not working with variable. I faced the same error so came up with a small custom directive as shown below,

```
import {Component, Directive, Output, EventEmitter, Input, SimpleChange} from 'angular2/core'

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[src]',
  host: {
    '(error)':'SetDefaultUrl()',
    '[src]':'src'
   }
})
class DefaultImage { 
  @Input() src:string;
  SetDefaultUrl() {
    this.src = 'images/angular.png';  // your default img path
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives:[DefaultImage],
  template: `
    <img [src]="invalidPath"/>
    `
})
export class App {
  invalidPath="abc";
}
```

**DEMO** :https://plnkr.co/edit/fD8zxd?p=preview

Comment: This looks cool! Actually I am using an image array `imgUrls[]` with `*ngFor`, so I need choose the second way, I succeed using a static link like your demo, but is there a way to give a link using Variable? I tried `onError="this.src=newUrl"`, `onError="this.src=this.newUrl"`, `onError="this.src={{newUrl}}"`, but neither works

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to get this working, is JavaScript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "imgUrl";

img.onload = function() {
   console.log("image was loaded successfully");
}

img.onerror = function() {
    console.log("there was an error loading the image");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is produced by the browser and there is nothing you can do to prevent it, except not passing an invalid URL.

The server would need to support an API where you can check for existing URLs using a AJAX calls without getting an HTTP error code back from the server in case you ask for an invalid URL.